# How to display date and time in magento website?

Tags: magento

I want to display date and time in the top of the magento website just below the login option.
Can anyone please tell how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking how to do this with php, or how to edit templates, or which files to edit? What have you tried?

Comment: can we display it from admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit header.phtml file in template/page/html/

insert this :

```
<div class="date-time">
<?php echo strftime('%c');?>
</div>
```

below

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

you can then add a class date-time in your css and adjust its position

look for different formats that can be supplied to strftime function to get datetime in different ways

Comment: Hey sulabh..actually i am new to magento..can u please give me some details to do this, as i did but it is not showing.

Comment: are you using the default theme? are you comfortable with editing phtml files?

Comment: go to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/  you will see header.phtml in that directory. you just have to add the lines above mentioned. refresh your cache and you will see the date and time.

Comment: It displayed..actually its not showing because of default theme..thanks sulabh !!

Comment: to achieve this you may have to write some javascript code.I havent worked with any such module.

Comment: isn't there any function in php to display a digital clock?

Comment: php is a server side script. it wont execute unless a request is made to the server and then page is refreshed. there is no request made to the server in the above clock

Comment: @David use some thing like this,at least this will make the clock visible.This is hidden because you have not specified any css.    <div style="background-color:#FFC3AD;position:relative;">
<?php echo strftime('%c');?>
</div>